# Python : extracting image source from HTML tag using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print the image Src tag value alone, I could successfully able to print the image tag value, But not able to get the src tag value.

```
import urllib3
import certifi
from urllib3 import PoolManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
manager=PoolManager(num_pools=3,cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
ca_certs=certifi.where())

base_url="https://app.tipotapp.com/docs/quickstart/"
page=manager.request('GET',base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.data, 'html.parser')
idd='creating-an-application'

for sibling in soup.find(id=idd).next_siblings:
    if sibling.name is None :
       continue
    elif sibling.name != 'h2'  :
       print(sibling.getText())
       if sibling.img is not None:
          print(sibling.img)
          #print(sibling.select_one("img"))
       else:
          continue  
    else :   
        break
```

The output which I'm getting now is,

Prints:
 ....Some expected strings.... Then the below output

```
<img alt="Student Management System" 
src="https://app.tipotapp.com/docs/images/quickstart/image_004.png"/>
```

In that, I want to print only src value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of an attribute, use the [`__getitem__(self, key)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) method.

> `tag[key]` returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag, throws an exception if it's not there.

Just replace the line `print(sibling.img)` with

```
print(sibling.img['src'])
```

Output:

```
https://app.tipotapp.com/docs/images/quickstart/image_002.png
https://app.tipotapp.com/docs/images/quickstart/image_002_1.png
https://app.tipotapp.com/docs/images/quickstart/image_004.png
```